# Check if this Variation ID exists in cart, then add another item to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to figure out how to add a specific item to cart, if this variation ID is added to cart. For example I have like 4 variations of a configurable product.

11264
11265
11266
11267

If product variation 11264 and 11265 is added to cart, then product with product ID 111 should also be added to cart. If  11266 and 11267 is added to cart, then product with product ID 222 should also be added to cart.

I found this code online that can add an item to cart based on the product category:

```
function aaptc_add_product_to_cart( $item_key, $product_id ) {

    $product_category_id    = 123; // cricket bat category id

    $product_cats_ids   = wc_get_product_term_ids( $product_id, 'product_cat' );

    if ( ! is_admin() && in_array( $product_category_id, $product_cats_ids ) ) {
        $free_product_id = 1522;  // Product Id of the free product which will get added to cart
        $found      = false;

        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->get_id() == $free_product_id )
                    $found = true;
                
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
        }        
    }    
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'aaptc_add_product_to_cart', 10, 2 );
```

That code works as intended. But now I want to make it conditional. So I modified this line:

```
if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
```

And changed it to:

```
if ($found  && WC()->cart->(11264,11265))
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart(111);
```

So that if variation ID 11264 or 11265 exists in cart, then add product ID 111. I think my syntax is wrong, but I'm not sure what's the next step. Tried googling it for hours but I cannot find any decent examples.

Comment: Your code might work, but what if I decide on the cart page to remove a product? 
and is it supposed to take product categories into account as in your existing code?

Comment: If you decide to remove a product on the cart page, then it will be removed. My goal is only to add another product automatically, like a free item based on the selected variation.

Comment: The code is actually working, as per category condition. But if I add a variation ID, it doesn't work anymore. T_T

Comment: Yes, your code may work, but if you remove a product on the cart page, the free added product will not be removed automatically. So your code only works partially. This is because you are using the wrong hook.

Comment: That's ok if it's not removed. That would be another question / additional function.

Comment: @Shaikh's code below worked for me. Thanks for the suggestions regarding the free item to cart removal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight Modification in foreach loop to get & compare variations might resolve the issue

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) { 

$variation_ids = array(11264,11265);

//check if variation exist in cart & if found add product in cart with ID 111

if( in_array( $values['variation_id'], $variation_ids ) ) {

WC()->cart->add_to_cart(111);
}
else {

//Do something

}
}
```

Comment: Wow that worked like magic! Thanks! Gotta bookmark this for future reference.